# ionic development server not reachable

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

Hey i have a new computer and now installed npm, ionic@3 and so on and tried to run my existing app. the app gets build and while running on my android device via debug the dev server gets started (my cmd is: ionic cordova run android --device -l -c -s )

> [15:55:08]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
>
> [OK] Development server running!
>        Local: http://localhost:8100
>        External: http://192.168.130.143:8100
>        DevApp: MyApp@8100 on MyPC

ionic info output:

```
ionic info

cli packages: (D:\app\trunk\node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3  
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1 


global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) 


local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9 Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios
4.5.4 Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2 System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 
Node              : v10.15.3 
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : Windows 10 


Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : D:\android_sdk 


Misc:
backend : pro
```

but the dev server is not reachable neither the local nor the external adress.
the app started on my device just gets a popup:

Application Error
The connection to the server was unsuccessfull. (http://192.168.130.143:8100)

i also read something that on android 8+ i need to add an additional tag for using unsecure http requests BUT i dont event get a response on my local computer.

what i tried:

- disable firewall and antivir.
- changed the port for the dev server
- run via npm like mentioned here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2699

when i run the serve with the cmd npm run ionic:build --debug the server starts it is reachable!! the page loads instant but shows a white page - the DOM is the right one.